# BLE onCharacteristicRead callback not called

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have implemented Bluetooth BLE and have made read/write commands successfully. But some time `onCharacteristicRead` is not getting called. What may be the issue ? Sometimes it is perfectly working, so read/write code is proper. Is it mandatory to pair the device to perform these actions ? or is just `connectGatt` is enough ?

Comment: It is hard to reply without some code. Are you calling [setCharacteristicNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean)) to enable notifications of a given characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, we need to find the available MLDP services on the BLE device.

```
mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
```

Once the service discovered, we need to iterate the MLDP services. Each service has a list of BluetoothGattCharacteristic. Identify our own Characteristic using the provided UUID and try to read the characteristic. Also, we need to set the below properties based on our hardware implementation.

```
setCharacteristicNotification
setCharacteristicIndication
setWriteType
```